# Removing blank spaces in specific column in pipe delimited file in AIX

Tags: unix, awk, sed, aix

Good morning. Long time reader, first time emailer so please be gentle.

I'm working on AIX 5.3 and have a 42 column pipe delimited file. There are telephone numbers in columns 15 & 16 (land|mobile) which may or may not contain spaces depending on who has keyed in the data.

I need to remove these space from columns 15 & 16 only ie

```
Column 15   |   Column 16 **Currently**
01942 665432|07865346122
01942756423 |07855 333567
Column 15   |   Column 16 **Needs to be**
01942665432|07865346122
01942756423|07855333567
```

I have a quick & dirty script which unfortunately is proving to be anything but quick because it's a while loop reading every single line, cutting the field on the pipe delimiter, assigning it to a variable, using sed on column 15 & 16 only to strip blank spaces then writing it out to a new file ie

```
cat $file | while read 

output

do

.....

fourteen=$( echo $output | cut -d'|' -f14 )

fifteen=$( echo $output | cut -d'|' -f15 | sed 's/ //g' )

echo ".....$fourteen|$fifteen..." > $new_file

done
```

I know there must be a better way to do this, probably using AWK, but am open to any kind of suggestion anyone can offer as the script as it stands is taking half an hour plus to process 176,000 records.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `awk` is better suited here

```
$ cat ip.txt 
a|foo bar|01942 665432|07865346122|123
b|i j k |01942756423 |07855 333567|90870

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {gsub(" ","",$3); gsub(" ","",$4)} 1' ip.txt 
a|foo bar|01942665432|07865346122|123
b|i j k |01942756423|07855333567|90870
```

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}` set `|` as input and output field separator
- `gsub(" ","",$3)` replace all spaces with nothing only for column 3
- `gsub(" ","",$4)` replace all spaces with nothing only for column 4
- `1` idiomatic way to print the input record (including any modification done )

Change `3` and `4` to whatever field you need

In case first line should not be affected, add a condition

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} NR>1{gsub(" ","",$3); gsub(" ","",$4)} 1' ip.txt
```

Comment: OP may or may not have left space in the header record in purpose. You might want to address that in your otherwise perfect answer?

Comment: Sundeep, you have saved my life!!!! This works perfectly and has obliterated the run time down to an astonishing 4.8 seconds!!! I cannot thank you enough.

Comment: @Darren_B you are welcome... see [what to do when you get answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Sundeep, I've turned the tick from grey to green as per instructions. Unfortunately, I've not got the privileges to upvote it or I would have. Thanks again.

Comment: Been using awk since... 1984 I guess.  Didn't know about the 1.

Comment: @pedz it is just a shortcut for `{print $0}` or `{print}`... for ex: when you filter `awk 'NR==2'` it is shortcut for `awk 'NR==2{print $0}'`... `NR==2` is condition..`1` is always true condition, can use any value that evaluates to true in conditional context

Comment: @Sundeep Ah.  I knew about 'NR == 2' ... I do that often.  Of course: 1 would always be true.  Very cool!