# Replace string between subsequent delimiters with substring

Tags: java, regex, delimiter, aix, csv

I have a 17GB pipe-delimited .txt file, and need to replace any strings that are more than 10 characters, between the 32nd and 33rd pipe, to their first 10 characters in order to populate a database column without opening the file in sublime-text; so it would need to be done through Java or AIX-BASH. On `regex101.com` I was trying to implement the ideas presented in the following post:

[RegEx: Match nth occurence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28438693/regex-match-nth-occurence)

but it doesn't limit the matched pattern only to my replacement-string.

Sample input:

`|12210|IA||15||i956-743||||||l.4073||||a5015b3ed||l.464939|IC|||06 06:18:17||wireered||ENTITY|wirvered|2||||NoPodfoundorpoddoesnothaveedgetob-rd=l.415.63Z|REY||||RY|REY||`

Intended output:

Change `...|NoPodfundddorpoddoesnot...|...` to `...|NoPodfundd|...`

Full output string after replacement/truncation:

`|12210|IA||15||i956-743||||||l.4073||||a5015b3ed||l.464939|IC|||06 06:18:17||wireered||ENTITY|wirvered|2||||NoPodfundd|REY||||RY|REY||`

Attempt at regex match:

`^(?:[^|]*\|){32}[^|]+\|` which matches everything from the start to the 33rd `|`, so `|12210.......l.415.63Z|`, but I want it to only match the string between pipes 32 and 33, specifically `NoPodfoundorpoddoesnothaveedgetob-rd=l.415.63Z`, for replacement purposes.

update 1; 10/18/17:

`(^(?:[^|]*\|){32}[^|]{0,10})([^|]*)(\|.*$)` group capture substitution with `\1\3` provides the desired result. But this match must have a flaw since it seems to be capturing a non-capturing group `(?:[^|]*\|)`.

update 2; 10/19/17:

Tried the following commands in PUTTY command line, but it does not edit the file:

```
cat subStrTest.txt
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{$33=substr($33,1,10)} 1' subStrTest.txt
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html suggests that

`string = substr(string,startIndex,numOfCharacters)`

is valid syntax, at least for `gawk`, but I don't know whether the assignment

`$33=substr($33,1,10)`

is valid for strings referenced with `$`, as in `$33` within `awk`

Comment: If you are running on unix/linux, why not use `sed`?

Comment: Try using awk. It's great for such cases.

Comment: There's no flaw, it's capturing the non-capture group because it's nested in a capture group, therefore it will be caught. Using other flavours of regex, you can do without the first capture group since the `\K` token can be used. Try `^(?:[^|]*\|){32}\K(([^|]{0,10})[^|]*)(?=\|)` on regex101. Unfortunately, Java doesn't support this token (as far as I'm aware)

Comment: Yes, it's a job for awk. Guess it would be something like this: `awk 'BEGIN { FS="|"; OFS="|"; } { $33= substr ($33,1,10); print; }'`

Comment: Please review the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46600250/removing-blank-spaces-in-specific-column-in-pipe-delimited-file-in-aix/46600539#comment80184535_46600539   I think with only slight adjustment, the solution will fit your needs.  It is essentially the same as Lorinczy's above.

Answer (score 0):

You can make match group and replace it another data
`^(?:[^|]*\|){32}([^|]+)\|`

Answer (score 0):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/Tuq5IM/1)

**Regex**

```
^((?:[^|]*\|){32})(([^|]{0,10})[^|]*)(?=\|)
```

**Replace**

```
\1\3
```